# Why is error handling not working for IndexError?

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm using a standard try/except syntax for skipping rows in a csv file that aren't streaming properly and therefore can't be downloaded. My code:

```
        for row in list_reader:
            media_id = row['mediaId']
            filename = row['mediaId']
            saveFile = media.get_item(media_id)
            stream_url = saveFile['streams'][0]['streamLocation']

            try:
                r = requests.get(stream_url, allow_redirects=True)

                with open(os.path.join('./media', filename), 'wb') as ofile:
                    ofile.write(r.content)
                    counter += 1
            except:
                IndexError
                print "error"
```

However after downloading a number of files the problem row comes up, the error is not handled and I get the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "downloadmedia.py", line 28, in <module>
   stream_url = saveFile['streams'][0]['streamLocation']
   IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've tried an if/else syntax instead, using the length of the stream_url variable, but this gives the same error. Can someone explain why the error handling doesn't work?

Comment: The error (list index is out of range) is coming from your for loop, not the code in the try/except block. That's why it isn't getting caught.

Comment: Your `IndexError` occurs before your `try...except` block and it should be `except IndexError:`. See docs at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: thanks, got it working now by moving the saveFile and stream_url variables into the try: block. appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, your try/except is in the wrong place. Through the error you provided, you can see that the index error occurs at the line `stream_url = saveFile['streams'][0]['streamLocation']`

You need to make sure the try/except is covering this line to prevent this.

```
for row in list_reader:
    try:
        media_id = row['mediaId']
        filename = row['mediaId']
        saveFile = media.get_item(media_id)
        stream_url = saveFile['streams'][0]['streamLocation']
        r = requests.get(stream_url, allow_redirects=True)
        with open(os.path.join('./media', filename), 'wb') as ofile:
            ofile.write(r.content)
            counter += 1
    except IndexError:
        print "error"
```